# How to make Divs Appear At Different Times

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

EDIT: (I'm very new to this kind of coding, so I'm aware that the following code I provided below is inefficient and probably borderline ridiculous. I'm looking for someone who could solve my problem and show me how to do it in an efficient way, rather than the copy/paste way I did below. Thanks!)

I have 7 different "trees" that I would like to appear on the page once the user has scrolled to a specific point. So far, the only way I could get the trees to appear is by fading them in, and still, with the code I have, they appear at the same time, and not one after the other as desired. Here's what I have:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree1").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree1").fadeOut("fast");
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree2").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree2").fadeOut("fast");
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree3").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree3").fadeOut("fast");
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree4").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree4").fadeOut("fast");
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree5").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree5").fadeOut("fast");
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree6").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree6").fadeOut("fast");
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 2800){
  $("#minitree7").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
  $("#minitree7").fadeOut("fast");
}
});
```

So, using this code, all seven trees "fadeIn" once the user has scrolled 2800 pixels from the top, and they "fadeOut" when the user scrolls above that.

What I'm aiming for is different: I want each tree to appear by bouncing upward (as if they were sprouting from the ground) instead of fading in, and I want them to happen one after the other.

I'm not sure if I want them to disappear if the user scrolls back above the trigger point, but  I'm really just concerned about how they appear for now.

If you could offer some advice, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: My head hurts. Why are you registering them all in separate event listeners?

Comment: ...and while we're at it, look into [caching and throttling](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/).

Comment: My apologies. I'm so incredibly new to this, so actually, if you could  point me in a more efficient direction, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

save yourself a big headache of making fadeIn/Outs for each element ID by setting a class on each of your elements

```
<div id="minitree1" class="minitrees">...</div>
<div id="minitree2" class="minitrees">...</div>
etc...
```

then script like so:

```
// cache reusable jQuery objects to variables
var $window = $(window), 
    $minitrees = $('.minitrees');

// one event with one scrollTop() check
$window.scroll(function(){
  if($window.scrollTop() > 2800){
    $minitrees.fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    $minitrees.fadeOut("fast");
  }
});
```

[**demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/95sdc/)

---

EDIT - independent tree animations:

[**demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/95sdc/2/)

```
var $window = $(window),
  $minitrees = $('.minitrees'),
  delay = 0,
  delayIncrement = 500;

$window.scroll(function () {
  if ($window.scrollTop() > 2800) {
    // loop through the trees increasing the delay each time
    $minitrees.each(function () {
      // 1. delay 0, 500, 1000
      // 2. show the tree
      // 3. animate the tree up from the ground (css starts with -100px animates to 0) 
      $(this).delay(delay).show().animate({
        bottom: '0'
      });
      delay += delayIncrement;
    });
    delay = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That certainly helps a lot with regards to cleaning up my code, but it still doesn't completely answer my question which was how to make each of those trees appear at different times.

Comment: Thank you. So far, in Jsfiddle, this looks awesome and the way I want it to go... but it doesn't seem to be working for me this way. My trees are different sizes, so I have different .png files for each of them. In your code, you are using the same file for each tree. What's the way around this?

Comment: you'll need to update the CSS.  My image was 100px high so `.minitrees { bottom: -100px }` was used, in your case set each tree element's height to negative whatever the image height is (ie `#minitree1 { bottom: -XXXpx }`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite as simple as it first appears.

You need :

- to fire the animations only when the threshold (2800) is crossed, not every time the `scroll` event fires.
- a way to make the trees "bounce upward (as if they were sprouting from the ground)".
- a way to give each tree its own timing.
- to stop any animations that are in progress before starting new ones.

Here's some code :

```
$(function(){
    //To keep the data tidy, we have an object with a bunch of properties 
    var treeData = {
        show = [0, 700, 200, 1000, {'top': '0px'}, 'easeOutElastic'],//minDelay(ms), maxDelay(ms), minDuration(ms), maxDuration(ms), cssMap, easing (adjust as necessary)
        hide = [0, 500, 50, 400, {'top': '200px'}, 'swing'],//minDelay(ms), maxDelay(ms), minDuration(ms), maxDuration(ms), cssMap, easing (adjust as necessary)
        timeOuts = {},
        animState = 0//0: <2800; 1: >=2800
    };

    //Note, animateTree() doesn't actually perform the animation, rather it returns a function that will perform the animation at some point in the near future.
    function animateTree(el, treeArray) {
        return function(){
            var duration = treeArray[2] + Math.random() * (treeArray[3] - treeArray[2]);
            var cssMap = treeArray[4];
            var easing = treeArray[5];
            $(el).animate(cssMap, duration, easing);
        }
    }
    function establishAnimation(el, treeArray){
            var id = el.id;
            if(treeData.timeOuts[id]) {
                clearTimeout(treeData.timeOuts[id]);
            }
            treeData.timeOuts[id] = setTimeout(animateTree(el, treeArray), treeArray[0] + Math.random() * (treeArray[1] - treeArray[0]));
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(treeData.animState == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() >= 2800){
            $(".minitree").stop().each(function() {
                establishAnimation(this, treeData.show);
            });
            treeData.animState = 1;
        }
        else if(treeData.animState == 1 && $(window).scrollTop() < 2800){
            $(".minitree").stop().each(function() {
                establishAnimation(this, treeData.hide);
            });
            treeData.animState = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

*untested*

Notes:

- Each minitree nedds to be given class="minitree";
- Need to install jQuery UI on the page to get the 'easeOutElastic' effect.
- As it stands the code assumes the trees are each hidden behind a mask and they are animated by changing their css `top` property. This will require tgheminitgrees to be styles with `position:absolute` or `position:relative` and for `top` to force the trees to be initially hidden. The code is organised to make this aspect simple to change if the design is different.
- To fire the animations only when the threshold (2800) is crossed, the last animation to be fired is tracked with the property `treeData.animState`.
- jQuery makes stopping animations simple, with its `stop()` method.
- The values in the arrays `treeData.show` and `treeData.hide` will need to be adjusted to get the animation effect you want. Comments in the code should be enough to explain what each value is for.